# Facing errors to deploy NodeJS app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my nodejs app but it gives me this error:

```
2019-11-25T18:16:16.927748+00:00 app[web.1]: > anonymous-forum-discussion@1.0.0 start /app
2019-11-25T18:16:16.927751+00:00 app[web.1]: > nodemon server.js
2019-11-25T18:16:16.927753+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-25T18:16:16.935126+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: nodemon: not found
2019-11-25T18:16:16.940397+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2019-11-25T18:16:16.940690+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-25T18:16:16.940929+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-11-25T18:16:16.941180+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
```

I tried other possible solutions posted on StackOverflow but it seems to be not working at all. I get an `Application Error` each time I deploy my nodejs app.

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "anonymous-forum-discussion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Anonymous Forum Discussion",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build && cd .."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3"
  }
}
```

My `Procfile`: `web: node server.js`

My `server.js` code:

```
var express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var models = require('./api/models/message');

var routes = require('./api/routes/routes');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
var app = express();
var Message = mongoose.model('Message')

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/discussion');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

routes(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("frontend/build"));
  console.log("production");
}

app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/build', 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);

console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

It would be really great if anyone can help me up with this issue to resolve `nodemon not found` error.

Comment: You typically don't want to deploy nodemon, as it is a development tool.

Comment: Just replace nodemon with node

Comment: Thanks @Udit, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by replacing `nodemon` to `node`.

As @JDunken pointed out, `nodemon` is a development tool. It cannot be deployed.